# print() is not concatenating into a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing the following:

```
print( 'Sent email', i+1 )
```

However, it does not print `Sent email 1` as I'd expect, it prints instead a list:

```
('Sent email', 1)
```

Any reason why it isn't concatenating the two parameters into a single string?

**EDIT: I am using Python 3.3.2 on Windows**

```
>>> import sys;print(sys.version)
3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: I didn't mention this before but I am using Python 3.3.2. Also the `print()` syntax is apparently also valid in 2.7

Comment: py3? Are you sure? What does `import sys;print(sys.version)` say?

Comment: @thg435 I have edited my question to include the results of your request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` is a statement in py2.x:

```
>>> i =0
>>> print 'Sent email', i+1 
Sent email `1
```

Adding `()` around it actually prints a tuple.

You can also import py3.x `print` function:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print ('Sent email', i+1)
Sent email 1
```

Comment: I'm using Python 3.3.2, so this doesn't apply to me.

Comment: @RobertDailey What you're saying is not possible in py3.x, unless you're doing something like : `print (('Sent email', i+1))`

Comment: Marking yours as the answer because I found out that the stupid "register extensions" still installed for Python 2.7.5 (which is also on my system) even though I told it not to, so I was unaware that it wasn't actually going to my Python3 install. Thanks!

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary It was me. I actually love your answers, but I felt that since OP was dealing with Python 3, it was not an appropriate answer for this question, informativeness aside. However, in the context of @RobertDailey's discovery of the "register extensions" (I don't even know what those are, to be honest!) talking about how the `print` statement works makes sense. As long as future viewers will see OP's discovery then I think this answer is perfectly fine. As a result I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @2rs2ts Even I am not a windows guy, so I've no idea what does "register extensions" do. Thanks for being honest. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
print('Sent email ' + str(i+1))
```

Or this, when running Python 2.x:

```
print 'Sent email', i+1
```

Comment: No need for me to give a redundant answer. The reason is that `print()` is assuming you are trying to print a tuple containing a string and an int, because `i+1` is an int. if you cast `i+1` to a string, the meaning of the comma changes.

Comment: @2rs2ts I thought print automatically converted types to a string. According to the docs: `print evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting object to standard output (see below). If an object is not a string, it is first converted to a string using the rules for string conversions.`. From: http://goo.gl/KUOgT

Comment: @RobertDailey I thought that in this case the expression would be considered a tuple. If you say `a = 1,2` then `print a` you get `(1, 2)` although maybe I'm wrong to think that.